# how to notify adapter after add single child?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-adapter

How to notify after `addСhild` method ?

I want to notify adapter after adding child so I tried to make this

```
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent
```

but it executed only one time after

```
addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener())
```

finished.

How to make this?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please elaborate what you are trying to do

Comment: hii , 
i want to get data from firebase 
then notify ListView after every child added
....
i tried to put notify adapter in addlistnerforsingle value but it executed only one time after all child Retrieved

Comment: I will suggest you to use RecyclerView instead. It's highly customisable. There you get a direct method namely RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItemInserted() to get notification of for each item added. This method is generally used in conjunction with RecyclerView.ItemAnimator to animate the insertion of each item

Comment: ok how to notify it after child added ?

Comment: ok where i should put this method ?

Comment: that depends on your usecase, call this method when you insert the item in the list containing the items

Comment: You are inserting a single item in your list, aren't you getting the position at which you are inserting it? Well if you are sorting the whole list or doing something like that then anyways you will have to call notifyDataSetChanged(), it's implementation is very optimised (if that is your concern). If it is getting inserted at the end of the list just pass the position of the last item (that will be itemCount - 1).. rest depends on your usecase

Comment: You'd call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding the item into the list. But please provide a [minimal, complete example that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can see enough context to be able to help.